# Bruteforce part of password in TrueCrypt

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, truecrypt, hashcat

I own a TrueCrypt container and I can't open it. I remember part of its password. So I want to bruteforce attack on it. I tried many parameters in oclHashCat but none worked (parameter problem). Can someone tell me please; how to pass correct parameters to oclHashCat to bruteforce my password?

Thank you

Comment: That's going to be a long sit ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good starting point to learn how the `Mask Attack` from oclHashcat works: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack

You need to add the commandline-parameter `-a 3` so hashcat knows your going to use a mask  attack.

Hashcat comes with some predefined mask's (you can define your own also):

```
?l = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
?u = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
?d = 0123456789
?s = «space»!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
?a = ?l?u?d?s
?b = 0x00 - 0xff
```

Example:

Lets take this as the password you are looking for: **PASSWDfA89**

You remember the `PASSWD` part but you didnt remember the other part: `fA89`

We see that the `fA89` part has lowercase and uppercase letters and numbers, 
then we need this mask: `?l?u?d`, but hashcat doesnt have it predefined so **we need to use a custom mask**.

For this, we need to add another commandline-parameter: `-1 [CUSTOM MASK HERE]`

The custom mask permits us to create our own charsets (up to 4) but we only need one.

The custom charset should look like this: `-1 ?l?u?d`

At the end, our command should be something like:

```
./oclHashcat-plus64.bin -m 6211 test.tc -a 3 -1 ?l?u?d PASSWD?1?1?1?1 -n 32 -u 2000
```

This is the important part: **`-a 3 -1 ?l?u?d PASSWD?1?1?1?1`**

Comment: Output: The manual use of the -n option (or --kernel-accel) is outdated. Please consider using the -w option instead. You can use --force to override this but do not post error reports if you do so.

Comment: When I replace `-n 32  -u 200` with `-w 3` that means high profile, this is the error i get: ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_UNKNOWN_ERROR

Comment: I had opensource nvidia driver. Replaced it with official one and worked for `-w 3`. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't I change `6211`?